# How to use Consumer API of Kafka 0.8.2?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm getting start with the latest Kafka document http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html. But I meet some problem when I try to use the new Consumer API. I've done the job with following steps:

**1. Add a new dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Add configurations**

```
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "host:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY, "range");
```

**3. Use KafkaConsumer API**

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(config);
consumer.subscribe("topic");
```

However, when I try to poll message from the broker, I got nothing but null:

```
Map<String, ConsumerRecords<String, String>> records = consumer.poll(0);
if (records != null)
    process(records);
else
    System.err.println("null");
```

And then I know what's wrong with the consumer after I checked the source code:

```
@Override
public Map<String, ConsumerRecords<K,V>> poll(long timeout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

To make matters worse, I cannot find any other useful information about the 0.8.2 API, since all usages about Kafka are not compatible with the latest version. Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The new KafkaConsumer API will only be available in 0.8.3 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Future+release+plan. Apparently there are some implementation in the trunk, although I have no clue about the state. For the time being I'm using the old consumer implementation.

Comment: Thanks @habsq . So among all old apis, which version is the best choice when using Kafka 0.8.x?

Comment: I'm using 0.8.1.1, don't know about the 'best' choice.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to write a Consumer on top of Kafka 0.8.2.1 to read the messages produced by the new Producer.

So far what I have got is that the Producer API is ready and usable, while on the consumer side we have to wait 0.8.3, as @habsq noted and you already find out that there is some code included for the Consumer, but it is still not functional.

So the client to use (the current Client API) are the one found in the "core" project of your current Kafka version, i.e. 0.8.2.1 (better not downgrade the client to any other version).

So for now we need to import two jars: one for the "new" java clients and one for the core project, depending also on the scala version you are using (I use 2.11).

In my case I use graddle to manage dependencies so I just need to import

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.8.2.1'
  compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.8.2.1'
}
```

When you update dependencies it will get all the needed libraries.

If you are using a different Scala version just change the version; anyway you can find all the different version or the full pom on maven central:
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.kafka%22%20AND%20v%3A%220.8.2.1%22

If you use those Consumer implementation all the current examples should work as usual.

PS ref: Kafka-users ml thread http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/153bepxet5/high-level-consumer-example-in-0-8-2

Comment: I explicitly put the two dependencies as in future we will just need the first on the "clients" jar and drop the one on "core" kafka. Actually now the client is also a dependency of the core, so who wants to be concise could just use the dependency on core kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can confirm that release 0.8.2.1 had problems in consuming messages. Now making a simple consumer with Java / Groovy and release 0.10.1.0, everything is working perfectly.

There is no more need for setting `PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY`.