# How to get consumers to work in Kafka 0.8 API

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

I am about to write a prototype for publishing and consuming kafka messages.
We do have a Cloudera infrastructure set up already (zookeepers, brokers, etc.), and I have played with the Kafka command-line tools successfully already, to produce and consume messages.

I am using `[org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 "0.8.2.1"]` as dependency, and have already been able to use the client API to set up a `KafkaProducer` which publishes messages with plain String content, and can be successfully read by the command-line consumer at the other side.

My question is: Is there a single code example on the [internets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internets) to show how to initialize a `KafkaConsumer`, and read that message on the other side, because I have been searching for it for days and none of the [code examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) seem to be working:

- They use classes or methods which are not even existing in he API itself (for example they seemingly pass the property-map into the constructor of `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig`, but no such constructor exists;
- calling `createJavaConsumerConnector` static method on the class `kafka.consumer.Consumer`... in which universe these things exist?).

And usually every example looks extremely over-complicated. I would expect a messaging framework to need a few lines of configuration for connecting to brokers, and some function to put and take to/from a queue or topic. Setting up the Producer for Kafka wasn't something extremely complicated, and I was expecting the Consumer to be similar.

It also seems I am [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857650/how-to-use-consumer-api-of-kafka-0-8-2) with this.

Comment: There are API changes in different Kafka version. Keep track of the version of the examples you look at. Have a look here for 0.8.2 API http://www.webhostingreviewjam.com/mirror/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html If this does not help, ask more precise question...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax So if I am understanding it correctly, the conclusion is that Kafka is definitely not something you would recommend to be put into production at this stage. I have used many messaging systems before, and they are not too complicated, you can `put` and `take` from a queue/topic, after a few lines of configuration/authentication (1 or 2, not 100s), and that's it. Kafka is in progress to arriving to that feature set, but I would try to avoid calling it a messaging platform without those very basic features in place.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  As for specific examples, I wrote the maven dependency I am working with, and the code example I linked to (for version 0.8.0, and based on the concept of [semantic versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Degree_of_compatibility), I would expect it to work with the version of my maven dependency), but it doesn't even compile. I you could point me to a code example which works with `0.8.2.1.` I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Kafka is absolutely production ready -- for some time already. See here for a list of companies using it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Powered+By Of course, you need to keep in mind your use-case, and it might happen that some other system meets your requirements best. For 0.8.2 examples, have a look here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/0.8.2/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples

Comment: Here is a nice comparison of Kafka vs. AMQP (watch from 28:45) https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Interestingly most of the times when the "why do we think kafka is the solution to our problem?" question is asked, the answer "these top companies are using it, we must have it too" often comes up. Not sure if that's a valid argument against the fact that I have never seen example code which compiles against 8.2.1. and able to read from a Kafka topic. It also seems we have different views on what production ready is. It's another question why a 0.x release is in production anywhere.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the link to the code examples, I'll try them out.

Answer (score 2):

First I want to mention, that there are a couple of API changes between Kafka `0.8.0`, `0.8.1`, and `0.8.2` (a mayor rewrite and simplification happened for `0.9.0` and `0.10.0`) -- thus, your question is a little open just asking for `0.8`.

To write a Java consumer for `0.8.2.2` you need to include dependency:

> This is for Scala 2.11 -- there are other Scala version available, too.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Do not use** `kafka-clients` **as artifactId for 0.8.x.**

A minimum example for a consumer receiving `<String,String>` key-value pair messages and prints them to `stdout` looks as follows:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

public class ConsumerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        props.put("group.id", "myGroup");

        final String topic = "test";

        ConsumerConnector consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));

        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1)); // number of consumer threads

        KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap).get(topic).get(0);

        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();

        // infinite loop
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(new String(it.next().message()));
        }

        // non-reachable code...
        consumer.shutdown();
    }
}
```

A full example -- using multiple consumer thread, including proper shutdown -- can be found here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

To test this, follow the [quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#quickstart) guide and send messages via Kafka's *console-producer*.

Comment: Tried the example, unfortunately still the same problem: it does not compile against 0.8.2. there is no such class as `kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig`, the closest is `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig` which has no such constructor as in [the example](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Consumer.java).

Comment: Interestingly [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.html) seems to be defined in Kafka `0.9.0.1` API, which is definitely not what I am using.

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work for you. `kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig` is there: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsumerConfig.scala

Comment: Did you include dependency "kafka-clients"? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients

Comment: No I only use the dependency mentioned in the question. Also, just printed the transitive dependency tree, and it doesn't show `kafka-clients` of any version

Comment: "kafka-clients" depends on "kafka" -- not the other way round. Thus the dependency tree does not show it. Includeing "kafka-clients" should resolve your problem about missing ConsumerConfig class.

Comment: Tried with org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients "0.8.2.1" as dependency on the classpath. Still no namespace like `kafka.consumer` exists, What maven dependency have you tried it with?

Comment: According to the jar file (from the mvn repository link from above) it is `org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.class`

Comment: You are right -- that is a little weird... Not sure why the imports are not correct...

Comment: Unfortunately `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig` still has no such constructor as in the example. The example was possibly written in an alternate universe, not in ours. Nice video though, the Kafka vs. AMQP.

Comment: So any ideas left what dependency I need which has the `kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig` class? As I said have managed to get a producer working before, so I am just curious, at least the dependency I am using is appropriate to get half of the intended purpose of Kafka working.

Comment: First, I want to apologize for all the confusion in this thread... I never used Kafka 0.8.x before. However, I dig into the topic and figured out the right answer. Replaced my previous answer with a complete new one... (also tested the example on my laptop).

Comment: Using version `0.8.2.2` definitely looks better, as the `kafka.consumer` namespace at least exists. I got until the point where I got back the `ConsumerIterator` from the `KafkaStream`. The problem now is that I never get back anything from it. `hasNext` always returns true, and `next` never returns anything (keeps running without timeout). I am publishing with my publisher code from another terminal, and if I use the console-consumer it does get the messages, so I don't understand why the Iterator doesn't return.

Comment: No error message? Did you check the logs? Hard to say... Can you try to send via consoles producer? Did you double check topic name etc?

Comment: `hasNext` seemingly always returns true, even before I have sent any message, and next just never terminates, and I have to exit. When I break the I get a `IllegalMonitorStateException: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease (:-1)`, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: If I try to get the message again, it says `IllegalStateException: Iterator is in failed state kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext (IteratorTemplate.scala:54)`

Comment: No idea. The example works for me. Do you use the exact same code?