# Kafka client upgrade from 0.8.2.1 to 2.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

I am planning to upgrade the kafka client from 0.8.2.1 to 2.1.1.

Need help with how to go about it?

My existing code is as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384777.
"kafka.consumer.KafkaStream" is depricated in 2.1.1

Need direction on how to go about this -

I Updated my pom to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Its not clear what exactly you are trying

Answer (score 0):

The 0.8 client was written in scala. The clients were rewrittem in java since 0.9. It is a completely new API. So a rewrite of your code is needed.